# set background image in blazor webassembly

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I tried to set background image for my div with codes below:

background-image: url(../wwwroot/resources/images/LoginBackground.jpg);

but it doesn't work, I try ' and " in url but it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path is the relative path after compilation, you can use `<img >` to judge.

```
<img src="./resources/images/LoginBackground.jpg"/>
```

If it can show the image, this path can be assigned to `url()`.

```
background-image:url('./resources/images/LoginBackground.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was helpful